# Filtering DropDownList items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am developing in .NET for the first time for my job and I have a question about interacting with data sources. I am using ASP.NET 4.5 Webforms, Entity Framework 4, SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

I have a database table called States with three columns: state_code, country_code, and description.

I have another table called Stores. This is a larger table but the relevant columns are state_id (same possible values as state_code) and isActive, a Boolean representing if that store is active or not.

I want to populate a DropDownList with the state_code column from the States table. However, I want to exclude:

- any states with country_code not equal to USA
- any states for which there does not exist a store where `isActive == true`. (i.e. exclude any states without active stores in the Stores table)

My question is: how do I go about doing this? Is this done through the Databind wizard or with my EDM classes? In the code-behind? I just need a nudge in the right logical direction. Please let me know if I can clarify anything further.

This is all the code I have so far for my DropDownList:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSourceID="StateStoreInfo" 
        DataTextField="state_code" DataValueField="state_code">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:EntityDataSource ID="StateStoreInfo" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=DBWebEntities" 
        DefaultContainerName="DBWebEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
        EntitySetName="States" Select="it.[state_code]">
  </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: In this scenario, you should look into using LINQ to help filter the data after you have accessed it using EF.

Comment: @ChrisBohatka Thanks! However, I'm not sure how to do that. Let's say I have created a new DropDownList and I have bound the state_code column to it, so it now shows all state_codes. What is my next step?

Comment: The filtering would need to occur before your data binding. This is a call that would occur on the codebehind. Gather your data set, using EF, then use LINQ on that to filter the results, then set that as your DropDownList data source.

Comment: Post your data binding code for the `DropDownList` control. Much more likely to get an answer and NOT have your question closed if you post code.

Comment: Try avoiding ASP DataSource controls, if possible. This becomes very difficult to manage with larger applications, and violates the SOLID principles.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I have posted what little code I currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ, the code would look something like this, with _repository being your data source coming from EF:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateStates();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateStates()
    {
        var statesNotInUS = (from s in _repository
            where s.CountryCode != "USA"
            select s).ToList();

        StateDropDownList.DataSource = statesNotInUS;
        StateDropDownList.DataBind();
    }
```

You can edit the LINQ query to filter by additional criteria as needed.

EDIT:
Typically your service call into the db will look something like this:

```
    public List<State> GetStates()
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"]))
        {
            return db.States.ToList();
        }
    }
```